Difference in permissions when installing an app as root vs running an app as root?
I'm trying to learn a bit more security in Linux and I'm struggling to understand the difference in permissions and access for an app installed via sudo, versus running an app via sudo. I have a few questions around this:

When installing an app using sudo, does this give the app full permission to do anything it wants to my system? Or are there restrictions on what this allows?
If an app was installed using sudo, is there any difference is access/permissions if the application is run with/without using the sudo command? (e.g., sudo pluma)
If a programme wasn't installed using sudo, is there a difference in permissions if this is run with the sudo command?

Thanks

The sudo command runs a command with root permissions.   If you install an app with sudo, the installer has root permissions.   If you run the application with sudo, it has root permissions.
The installer, when run as root, can modify the system, install services that run as any user and start automatically, and assign permissions to the application.  It may have options to give the application elevated permissions, but usually does not.  For example, the sudo command itself can be installed with a package manager...  and installing apache typically will set it up to start as boot as the apache user.  Installers for normal applications likely would not assign any special permissions.
Note that some installers (e.g., snap) can actually install the application so that it runs with reduced permissions inside a container.
If the installer doesn't grant the application additional permissions or install it in a container to reduce permissions, then after the app is installed, when it is running it normally without sudo, it will have the permissions of the user who ran it.
If you install an application without sudo, presumably you are installing it in your home directory.  As such, you own all the files in the application and it is in your environment which presumably is not shared with other users.  Installing it with sudo would (probably) install it for all users and the installed files would (probably) not be owned by you.  In theory, installing with sudo might be more secure, where installing in your account might be less secure, as your user account can modify the application after it is installed.  This is less important if you aren't sharing the application with other users.
Ownership of the installed application files might be important if, say, your user account accidentally ran malware that looked for things to modify or looked for things to delete or corrupt.
Note that running applications with sudo that are not aware of elevated permissions can have very bad results.  For instance, if the application creates config files and you run it with sudo, those config files may be created in your user account but owned by root, which might then prevent the application from running correctly without root as it may not be able to read or modify those config files in your account.  Similarly, if you run it with sudo and then save data, it can save it anywhere in the system leading to junk files in strange places that you might not even be able to find when you look for them later.
